Dividing one dimension value by another
I'm trying to get a percentage of those hired out of people who were interviewed:

Is there a way to divide Hired/Interviewed by Race and Gender?
Thanks in advance

What does a row in your data set look like? i.e. what are the columns in your data set? What do you have on the text shelf in your screen shot? What is PoC? is it relevant to your question? Ideally, post a few lines of sample data and what you think the correct result would be for that sample.

Also, when defining percentages, be ready to answer the question - percentage of WHAT? so do you want to know the percentage of females hired with respect to the  number of females interviewed? or with respect to all candidates interviewed? or of all people hired? The simplest way to calculate percentages with Tableau is with quick table calcs, and then you can use the "compute using" feature to define what you want, i.e. percentage of WHAT

You need to create 2 calculated field, where People is equal to interviewed and the second one equal to hired.
you need to create another calculated field where you divide those newly made column again by each other..
